# Curl - JSON_PARSER_ERROR Unexpected character

Tags: json, curl

getting the following error using curl with salesforce, I'm trying to update a record. Have I formatted this wrong or am I missing something

Many thanks for your help

```
curl https://##url##/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Account/##acountID## -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"BillingStreet" : "1 Fake Street", "BillingCity" : "London"}' -X PATCH
```

```
[ {
  "message" : "Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:2]",
  "errorCode" : "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
} ]curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is first character
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1 Fake Street,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: BillingCity
curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is first character
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 8
```

Comment: Are you on Windows 10? Which `curl --version` do you use? Have you tried replacing your single quotes (after "-d") by double quotes and replaced the other double quotes (of the POST data) by the combination of backslash - double quote?

Comment: Thanks for getting curl 7.55.1 for Windows and curl 7.64.0 on Linux

Comment: like this "{\"PersonEmail\":"\simon@theway.com\"}"   ?

Comment: With the above I get [ {
  "errorCode" : "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
  "message" : "HTTP Method 'POST' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,PATCH,DELETE"
} ]

Comment: Your correction is okay. But do you still have `-X PATCH` in the end? This shouldn't send a POST, it should send a PATCH request.

Comment: Got it working with "{\"PersonEmail\":\"simon@theway.com\"}", thanks for you help